# login functionality in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add login functionality to my asp.net 2013 application using an access database. How to i get more than one user role to access the same page??

this is the public static bool ive created

```
public static bool doesUserHaveRole(string username, string roleToTest)
{
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM UsersTb WHERE LoginName=@LoginName";
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    oleDbConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, oleDbConn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", username);
    OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows == false) return false;
    dr.Read();
    string role = dr["UserRole"].ToString();
    if (role == roleToTest) return true;
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: What's this have to do with php?

Comment: Is this WebForms or MVC? And why aren't you using the User provider?

Comment: Describe your problem clearly ..

Comment: its for a school project! we have to use visual studio 2013 to create an application, im using MS access as my database because i dont know sql, my problem is that Im trying to give rights to certain users to access certain pages which is fine, the problem comes up when i try to give more than one user access tothe same page. Admin always over rides the others

Comment: Tag your question properly. Currently it just says "C#". If it really is WinForms, then tag it as WinForms. But the first sentence says it's ASP.Net 2013, and it can't be both WinForms and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting all rows for a user and checking all rows, you can pass the role id to your query.

And you can return count of the matching rows:

```
public static bool doesUserHaveRole(string username, string roleToTest)
{
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM UsersTb WHERE LoginName=@LoginName AND UserRole=@UserRole";
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    oleDbConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, oleDbConn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserRole", roleToTest);
    OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    return dr.Read() && ((int) dr["C"]) > 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot I will try to it implement now

Comment: how do i call the function using an int this is what i had before using one row do i do a does user have UserRole??                                                                         if                   (utilities.doesUserHaveRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin") == false) Response.Redirect("/Account/Register.aspx");

Comment: function on the page does not allow any one in no matter what the role is set to on the database right now I have if (utilities.doesUserHaveRole("Reader", "Admin") ==false) Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx"); but this blocks all users access to the page even when logged in

Comment: Sorry I made a stupid mistake. Updated the answer :)

Comment: I am happy it has worked and you're welcome :) You can mark it as an answer to help people with the same problem